# Calculus- Alternating series error estimation theorem

Tags: calculus

In alternating series error estimation theorem $$a_n = (-1)^{n+5} \frac{n}{n^2 + 9}$$
and the error of the magnitude less than $10^{-8}$.

While solving I substituted $n = n + 1$. Then $a_{n+1} < 10^{-8}$, $\frac{n^2 + 2n + 10}{n + 1}>10^8$
Solving this $n$ comes out to be $10^8$ which seems incorrect . Where is the mistake?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please type your questions instead of posting images.  Images can't be browsed and are not accessible to those using screen readers.  If you need help formatting math on this site, here's a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) To begin with, surround math expressions (including numbers) with `$` signs and use `_` for subscripts.  `$x_1$` comes out as $x_1$.

Comment: Can u share what am I doing wrong in the question

Comment: How can i solve this question

Comment: Its actually (-1)^(n+5)   + n/(n^2+9)

Comment: Well the solution is actually $n=10^8-1$, but close enough.  Why do you think it's wrong?

Comment: Because n is the value of

Comment: I can't understand what you mean.  That isn't even a sentence.  Value of what?

Comment: Because n is the value of Smallest number of terms needed to estimate the entire sum and n seems to be too big , so i was unsure

Comment: Yes, the series converges very slowly.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that